# normal list 'type' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, pycharm, typeerror

```
numbers = [2 , 5 , 10]
for n in range[1,20]:
    if n in numbers:
        continue
    print (n)
```

I'm getting this error

```
C:\Python34\python.exe "F:/google drive/3d projects/python/untitled/0001.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "F:/google drive/3d projects/python/untitled/0001.py", line 2, in <module>
        for n in range[1,20]:
    TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable
```

looked for an answer but didnt find it im new to python so dont be angry if this is a stupid qustion  the weird thing this code is used exactly on a tutorial on youtube and its working 
i use pycharm  is there any thing wrong in my python app or ide

Answer (score 7):

`range` is a function it should be `range(1,20)`

That is the line `for n in range[1,20]:` should read

```
for n in range(1,20):
```

As you can see in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#range)

> `range(start, stop[, step])`
>    This is a versatile ***function*** to create lists containing arithmetic progressions

(Emphasis mine)

A small demo

```
>>> numbers = [2 , 5 , 10]
>>> for n in range(1,20): 
...    if n in numbers:
...        continue
...    print (n)
1
3
4
6
7
8
9
11
12
13
14
15
16
17
18
19
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use parenthese rather than square brackets, you had `for n in range[1,20]:` this should be `for n in range(1,20):`:

```
In [106]:

numbers = [2 , 5 , 10]
for n in range(1,20): #<--
    if n in numbers:
        continue
    print (n)
1
3
4
6
7
8
9
11
12
13
14
15
16
17
18
19
```

Answer (score 0):

The line `for n in range[1,20]:`must be `for n in range(1,20):`

```
numbers = [2 , 5 , 10]
for n in range(1,20):
    if n in numbers:
        continue
    print (n)
```